# String Comparison shows error on String retrieved from flash[:alert]

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, string-comparison

I am having a javascript code to compare two strings and execute code accordingly.

One String retrieved though rails ***flash[:alert]*** and other ***specified locally***.

```
     <% if flash[:message].present? %>
         var message=new String("<%= flash[:message] %>");
         var message_status=message.localeCompare("mail_sent");
         if(message_status==0)
         {
           // if code....
         }
         else
         {
           alert(message);
           // else code....
         }
    <% end %>
```

Here, ultimately, i am trying to ***compare two Strings***. One retrieved through `flash[:alert]` and other specified locally i.e `mail_sent`.

What I observe is

`It always goes through the else part even though the message displayed in the else part alert is mail_sent.`

*Please Note that when i replaced the **<%= flash[:message] %> with String locally**. It executed the **if part***. 
i.e

`var message=new String("mail_sent");`

***instead of***

`var message=new String("<%= flash[:message] %>");`

***Could anyone say why is it so ?***

***What is need to be done in order to compare two strings in this way?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your controller. 
There might be something wrong there.
Are you sure you are setting flash[:message] ="mail_sent" ????

Comment: Oh boy, I set the value `flash[:alert]=mail_send`. You saved my day one.